# AWS CLI - describe-db-instances by Resource ID? Or other unchanging value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Basically I want to run a describe-db-intances command to check the status of a DB Instance that I am renaming. I'm running into an issue because it seems (and I'm surprised this is the case) that I can only query it by instance identifier. However, I'm renaming the DB and this value will change. I want to double check that the rename is complete and the DB is showing Available status, but the command is having issues because the server I'm checking disappears as soon as the rename takes effect.

Is there any way to check by something like Resource ID?  that will never change.

Comment: It changes because it's creating a completely new RDS instance on the backend. It's not the same instance anymore. The UI is providing convenience for instance replacement, in the API that field is immutable.

Comment: Hmm makes sense. I guess I can accomplish this by just waiting until the new instance name appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old question but you can actually use filters for this. e.g.

```
describe-db-instances --filters "Name=dbi-resource-id,Values=db-ACBDEFG..."
```